# B-splines with Scipy : can I add a datapoint without full recompute?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, bspline

I have a bspline created with scipy.interpolate.splrep with points (x_0,y_0) to (x_n,y_n). Usual story. But I would like to add a data point (x_n+1,y_n+1) and appropriate knot without recomputing the entire spline. Can anyone think of a way of doing this elegantly?

I could always take the knot list returned by splrep, and add on the last knot of a smaller spline created with (x_n-2, y_n-2) to (x_n+1,y_n+1) but that seems less efficient than it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Spline construction is a global process, so if you add a data point, you really need to recompute the whole spline. Which involves solving an N-by-N linear system etc.

If you're adding many knots sequentially, you probably can construct a process where you're using a factorization of the colocation matrix on step `n` to compute things on step `n+1`. You'll need to carefully check the stability of this process. And `splrep` and friends do not give you any help here, so you'll need to write this yourself. (If you do, you might find it helpful to check the sources of `interpolate.CubicSpline`).

But before you start on that, consider using a local interpolator instead.

If all you want is to add a *knot* given data, then there's `scipy.interpolate.insert`.